# Django: updating the DB asynchronously

Tags: django

I develop a django app where lots of DB updates could/should be deferred to later time.

What would be a good way to update the DB in a background batch job?

One way I could think of is to have a message queue that would contain raw SQL statements.

The django app would fill the queue with raw SQLs when the update should be done asynchronously.

A simple background job, (in a different un-related process), would just deqeue and execute the SQL statements it in its own pace..

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Celery is often used for this.

Start with this related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/celery.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this good [review](http://www.darkcoding.net/software/choosing-a-message-queue-for-python-on-ubuntu-on-a-vps/) about the subject. It recommends [Gearman](http://gearman.org/)

Seems a lighter solution than Celery.. I think I will give it a try